# Streaming a video while also caching it for future playback on Android

Tags: android, video-streaming

It is very easy to use the videoview to stream a video from a uri. The problem is that next time the user wishes to watch this video it will stream again. I would like to be able to download the video so that future playbacks can happen offline. I guess the problem here is that the download is not happening in the background and if the user navigates away the "download" would be cancelled.

The other way of going about this would be to create my own streaming mechanism. I would start downloading the video file in the background, using the videoview to play the partially downloaded file while it is downloading. I am not sure how seeking or showing the buffering loader would work in this case.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: See [AndroidVideoCache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache) library. It does exactly same thing you described

Answer (score 0):

I know it can be done. Just unsure how to do it. I had an app called vplayer that used to do it, but when I rooted and reinstalled it on my Nexus 7, the app disappeared and was unable to be downloaded again. There are some codecs to the app floating around in the Play Store but not the original app smh.